# How to check leaflet map has any polygon?

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am using leaflet map, which can contain polygon(s). 
I want to check that map has any polygon and if it has then i want to find coordinates of that polygon?

Answer (score 3):

```
map.eachLayer(function(layer){
    if(layer instanceof L.Polygon && !(layer instanceof L.Rectangle) ){
        console.log(layer.getLatLngs());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.
Can you tell me one more thing? i can also draw polygon on map. I have removed that by clearLayers() function but it still shows in map layer. How can i remove this from map?

Comment: can you pls add the code where you adding the polygon to the map and how you call clearLayers. Because clearLayers can't called on `map` so you are using a layergroup.

Comment: // Initialise the FeatureGroup to store editable layers
this.editableLayers = new L.FeatureGroup();
this.map.addLayer(this.editableLayers);
///add layer while draw
this.map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
  var type = e.layerType,
    layer = e.layer;

  if (type === 'marker') {
    layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
  }
  layer.on("click", function(e) {
    console.log(" Points: " + e.target.getLatLngs());
  });
  that.editableLayers.addLayer(layer);
});
///remove function
    public RemoveDrawPolygon(){
        this.editableLayers.clearLayers();
    }

Comment: It is working for me ... I think this is because leaflet draw adds already the layer to the map / a group and then you adding it again to another group. And when you remove it, you are removing it from the editableLayers group but not from the leaflet-draw group